# Python: %timeit operation

Tags: python, ipython, timeit

```
l = range(100)
%timeit [i**2 for i in l]

10000 loops, best of 3: 41.6 µs per loop
```

I am confused on how to explain the above output.

Answer (score 4):

`[i**2 for i in l]` has been called by `%timeit` 10000 times.

Every time this line of code is being executed, `%timeit` measures the time it took. Note that `%timeit` doesn't always run an operation 10000 times. It runs it once and decides how many times the operation should be run. The goal is to have enough measurements while not needing 1 hour to give an estimate. If you try it with a larger `l`, `%timeit` might run only 1000 times.

Your computer might be doing some other operations at the same time (e.g. Browser, playing music, ...) so some executions might be really slow and shouldn't be taken into account.

`%timeit` takes the 3 shortest executions out of the 10000 times, and displays their average. Your computer probably wasn't doing much during those executions, so the corresponding time might be representative of the time it would take if your computer was only concentrating on this task.

`%` is used in order to tell iPython it's a iPython command, not a Python command. If you try it in normal Python console, it will fail with a `SyntaxError`. You can also type `%history` in iPython.

Comment: Thank you very much. I get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior of [`%timeit`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit), it performs multiple runs in order to attain more robust results.

```
l = range(100)
%timeit [i**2 for i in l]

10000 loops, best of 3: 41.6 µs per loop
```

No. of loops executed is 1000, and it gives you the best out of three execution time.

Comment: what is the meaning of best of 3? and also, why there is a % sign before timeit?

Comment: It's a magic function used in ipython, you can use it this way without importing the module. Also since your range was 100, it ran 3 times -> 10000 and hence the best execution time out of three.

Comment: why does the range of 100 equal to run 3 times? and when i change the range the loops number change, what does it mean?

Comment: it is the default behavior(**3**) which you change `%timeit -r some_number` to repeat it for number of time, please go through the docs.